# Where is the .xsession file in linux mint?

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, desktop, desktop-environment

I would like to know how I can use start up scripts in `.xsession` in order to change the look of my Desktop, I assumed `.xsession` was in my home directory so I performed at my home directory: `ls -a` to list all the hidden files, that start with a dot, but there was no `.xsession` file. So, I searched the whole file system beginning from the root with:

```
ls -Ra / | grep .xsession
```

but unfortunately it did not find this .xsession file either.

Comment: Just create it ... But as you tagged this Xfce : Xfce has a session manager, to configure it go in "Settings"/"Session and startup".

Comment: If there's no `.xsession`, the display manager starts a default session (which one depends on the distribution and on the display manager, I don't know what it is on Mint). It's normal not to have one.

Answer (score 0):

on most distros, the global xsession is `/etc/X11/Xsession`. It might also be `~/.xinitrc`.